# jQuery detect accents in textbox keypress event

Tags: jquery, events

I'd like to know whether it is possible to detect accents (á,ő,ű,ö,etc.) at the jQuery keyboard events.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: accents === (á,ő,ű,ö) in what form?

Comment: Perhaps a regex with [^a-zA-Z0-9] is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with regex...

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){
    var myRegex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/;
    var text = $(this).val();
    if(myRegex.test(text)){
        alert('accent detected');
    }
});
```

See this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3A5d/)

Greetings...

Comment: It's not working. This solution detects any chars with or less accents.

Answer (score 0):

on key press event u can see the ASCII code of the the character using this table of ASCII http://www.asciitable.com/index/extend.gif

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @MG_Bautista, but your answer is wrong.
In your example, if you try with some characters like !, ?, it says that 'accent detected'. But @sada needs only accented characters
You must change the regex:

```
var MyRegex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9!"'\.,{}\[\]\(\)\\=|°#$%&/?¿¡´+*-_]/;
```

maybe I forgot some "special" character. So, **the real solution** needs to be detect only the characters you need and not the not needed ones.

```
var MyRegex = /[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôû]/; //and all the ones you need to detect
if (MyRegex.test(text)){
    alert("accent detected");
}
```

Important:
If you need to test every character, you have to iterate over the string.

I hope this helps, 
Bye.